# compare rising edge occured before or after an other edge with verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, design

I would like to write a verilog code to generate RTL level for **signal B** as in the figure. It has been a long time since I wrote verilog at school so I am quite rusty at this.
Let's say I have two **signals A, B** as in the picture and I need to generate the **signal C** with the description below.

The **rising edge of signal C** is determined as follows:

1. At the falling edge of signal A if rising edge of signal B is occured before falling edge of signal A.
2. At the rising edge of signal B if rising edge of signal B is occured after falling edge of signal A.
   (you may want to look at the picture to understand the rule easier)

The duty cycle of signal C is equal to duty cycle of signal A.

I am stuck at the part to compare whether the rising edge of signal B is occured BEFORE or AFTER falling edge of signal A.
Hope someone could help me on this.

[image]

Comment: What are the pulse-widths of the signals? (ns? us?) And what sort of resolution to do need? (exact or is clock sampled ok).

Comment: "The duty cycle of signal C is equal to duty cycle of signal A." - that doesn't appear to be what is shown in your diagram.

Comment: Are the signal edges assumed to be clean? (i.e. no bounce, spurious pulses, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't quite enough information in your question as to the best way to approach this. However I will make two assumptions:

1. The signals are conditioned (i.e. no spurious pulses or noisy edges)
2. You are able to sample the signals with a fast clock to make them synchronous. This means you can simply check the signals at discrete time points rather than asynchronously.

Given these assumptions, the approach I would use is to detect the edges of the signals using a simple synchronous edge detector. You can then use a state machine to determine the order of events.

```sv
//First we sample the signals with fast clock and perform edge detection.
//This gives us a series of discrete time points to work with
reg aDly, bDly;
reg aFall, bRise;
always @ (posedge fastClock) begin
    aDly <= a;
    bDly <= b;
    aFall <=  aDly && !a; //Falling edge of a when aDly high and a low.
    bRise <= !bDly &&  b; //Rising edge of b when bDly low and b high.
end

reg someEvent; //Set this high when c needs to fall.

//Now we do the logic for C with a state machine.
localparam IDLE_STATE   = 2'b00;
localparam AFIRST_STATE = 2'b01;
localparam BFIRST_STATE = 2'b10;

reg [1:0] stateMachine;
reg       c;

always @ (posedge fastClock or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset) begin
        stateMachine <= IDLE_STATE;
        c            <= 1'b0;
    end else begin
        case (stateMachine) begin
            IDLE_STATE: begin //Wait for the start of an event sequence.
                //If the start of a sequnece
                if (bRise && aFall) begin
                    //If both happen at the same time
                    c               <= 1'b1;            //C goes high immediately.
                end else if (aFall) begin
                    //If falling edge of a comes first
                    c               <= 1'b0;            //C stays low.
                    stateMachine    <= AFIRST_STATE;    //And go on to wait for b rising.
                end else if (bRise) begin
                    //If rising edge of b comes first
                    c               <= 1'b0;            //C stays low.
                    stateMachine    <= BFIRST_STATE;    //And go on to wait for a falling.
                end else if (someEvent) begin
                    //Work out when C should go low - I can't tell this from your description
                    c               <= 1'b0;            //C goes low.
                end
            end
            AFIRST_STATE: begin //Wait for rising edge of b
                if (bRise) begin
                    //Once rising edge of b occurs,
                    c               <= 1'b1;            //C goes high.
                    stateMachine    <= IDLE_STATE ;     //Return to idle.
                end
            end
            BFIRST_STATE: begin //Wait for falling edge of a
                if (aFall) begin
                    //Once rising edge of b occurs,
                    c               <= 1'b1;            //C goes high.
                    stateMachine    <= IDLE_STATE ;     //Return to idle.
                end
            end
        endcase
    end
end
```

You will need to work out what logic to use to determine when C should go low. I can't tell this from your question.

If you want a fixed width, you could use a counter which is triggered when C goes high.

Comment: Thanks. To make the problem easier, let change the condition C goes low when signal B goes low. That doesn't make fixed width but it is OK now.

Comment: @anhnha in which case add a falling edge detector for the B signal (bFall) and use that signal as 'someEvent'.